# How can I fix Multer Gridfs Storage error "Error creating storage engine. At least one of url or db option must be provided"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I am trying to make the functionality of uploading images to MongoDB using GridFS. I am getting the error please have a look

**Complete Error:**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
K:\Development\MindFuel\Backend\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:71
            throw new Error('Error creating storage engine. At least one of url or db option must be provided.');
            ^

Error: Error creating storage engine. At least one of url or db option must be provided.
    at new GridFsStorage (K:\Development\MindFuel\Backend\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:71:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (K:\Development\MindFuel\Backend\Helpers\Libraries\imageUpload.js:9:18)      
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (K:\Development\MindFuel\Backend\Routers\story.js:2:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)

Node.js v20.11.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**Connect Database file**

```
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const connectDatabase = async () => {    

    const conn = await mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    let gfs;
    
    conn.once('open', ()=>{
        // Init stream
        gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
        gfs.collection('images');
    })
    console.log("Connected database successfully");
}
   module.exports = connectDatabase;
```

**Here is my image Upload file in NodeJS**

```
const CustomError = require("../error/CustomError")
const crypto = require('crypto');
const multer = require("multer")
const { GridFsStorage } = require("multer-gridfs-storage")
const path = require("path")

// create storage engine

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: process.env.MONGO_URI,
    file: (req, file) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
          const fileInfo = {
            filename: filename,
            bucketName: "images"
          };
          resolve(fileInfo);
        });
      });
    }
  });

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {

    allowedMimeTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

    if (!allowedMimeTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        return (new CustomError("Please provide a valid image file ", 400), null)
    }

    cb(null, true);

}

const imageUpload = multer({ storage, fileFilter })


module.exports = imageUpload;
```

My process.env.MONGO_URI variable is in the form: URI=mongodb+srv://...

**Any help is greatly appreciated :)**

Comment: Have you tried hard coding the URL in the connection and GridFSStorage decleration (i.e.not from your ENV) and seeing if the code works? Or at least logging the value of process.env.MONGO_URI to make sure it's what you think it is and not empty or undefined?